# Access to Google Ads Data Hub

Tags: ads-data-hub, google-ads-data-hub

I was going through the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/ads-data-hub/guides/run-queries) to submit queries in google's ads data hub.

On the documentation, it says

> You should first write and test your query in the `adh` project of the [Ads Data Hub sandbox for advertisers](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/queries/full-circle-sandbox-data) or the [Ads Data Hub sandbox for vendors](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/queries/full-circle-vendor-sandbox). If it is error free, you are ready to run your query against real data.

My queries:

a. I cannot find the `adh` project in either of [Ads Data Hub sandbox for advertisers](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/queries/full-circle-sandbox-data) or [Ads Data Hub sandbox for vendors](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/queries/full-circle-vendor-sandbox). **Do we require any permissions for viewing `adh` dataset?**

b. When opening the [Ads data hub interface](https://adsdatahub.google.com/u/0/), the I get the following message on screen.

> You do not have access to this application. Your account may not be associated with an active Ads Data Hub customer.

Any help or pointers will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know, the ADH is still in early phase and you need to contact your Google representatives to get access to it. This product is pretty new, so only a few clients have the ADH access.

Comment: We don't have a lot of ads, so no sales rep :(. Got the same reply from google support though.